# Segmentation fault when using move_base rotate_recovery

Tags: move-base, local-costmap, footprint

**Summary:**

In a rotate_recovery behavior called by move_base, the following code is telling me that getRobotFootprint() has an impossibly big size, and I get a segmentation fault when accessing the first point. Why could it be?

```
const std::vector<geometry_msgs::Point>& f = local_costmap_->getRobotFootprint();
ROS_ERROR("Size of vector f: %zu", f.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < f.size(); ++i) {
    const auto& point = f[i];
    ROS_WARN("  x: %.2f, y: %.2f, z: %.2f", point.x, point.y, point.z);
}
```

**Long story:**

I am trying to write my own rotate recovery behavior (https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/noetic-devel/rotate_recovery).

So to start I am trying to create a plugin that does exactly the same as the above but call it `rotate_recovery2`.

I literally copied the `rotate_recovery` folder, changed the name of all `rotate_recovery` files and folders to `rotate_recovery2`, change all instances of `rotate_recovery` to `rotate_recovery2` in the `CMakeLists` and `package` and `rotate_plugin` files, and in the `rotate_recovery2.cpp` and `rotate_recovery2.h` files, I simply changed the namespace to `rotate_recovery2`, and in the case of the `.cpp` file I replaced the import (`#include <rotate_recovery2/rotate_recovery2.h>`), and the export class (`PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(rotate_recovery2::RotateRecovery, nav_core::RecoveryBehavior)` ).

The code is therefore the same. I have created a new workspace, copied the package inside the `src` folder, built the package (`catkin_make`), sourced it.

But if I load the following rosparams:

```
recovery_behaviors:
  - name: 'costmap_reset_far'
    type: 'clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery'
  - name: 'costmap_reset_close'
    type: 'clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery'
  - name: 'rotate_recovery2'
    type: 'rotate_recovery2/RotateRecovery'

costmap_reset_far:
  reset_distance: 3.0
  layer_names: ["obstacle_laser_layer"]

costmap_reset_close:
  reset_distance: 1.5
  layer_names: ["obstacle_laser_layer"]

rotate_recovery2:
  sim_granularity: 0.017
  frequency: 20.0
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.01
  max_rotational_vel: 0.25
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.1
```

If I run move_base: `rosrun move_base move_base odom:=mobile_base_controller/odom cmd_vel:=nav_vel __name:=move_base`.

When the robot gets lost I get a **Segmentation Fault**.

After some debugging, it happens in this line:

```
double footprint_cost = world_model_->footprintCost(x, y, theta, local_costmap_->getRobotFootprint(), 0.0, 0.0);
```

I don't know much cpp, but I have been playing with it, and the following:

```
const std::vector<geometry_msgs::Point>& f = local_costmap_->getRobotFootprint();
ROS_ERROR("Size of vector f: %zu", f.size());
```

Prints `Size of vector f: 18254858764495155175`, which has to be wrong, and when I try to access any element in the footprint, it gives me the segmentation fault.

Why is this happening? How to fix it? I am completely lost, I think the problem is in local_costmap, which is passed by move_base, but I am probably not understanding something.